# Functions in Haskell (specifically swap function)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc

Alright I know that this question has been asked before, but no answers have compiled. I've researched Haskell function tutorials to no avail. Basically I just want to know how to declare a function in Haskell and how to call it. Most of the tutorials I've found are answering how to do this with ghci, which I understand should be basically the same thing, but I need to write this in a .hs file and compile with ghc for a school assignment. Basically I'd like something like this:

```
main = do

let list = [1,2,3,4]
-- declare swap
swap (list !! 0) (list !!2)
-- Or
swap 1 2 list
```

I'm using ghc version 7.4.1 which I understand isn't the latest version, but it's not a terribly old version either, so it shouldn't make a difference here, should it? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You say you have researched tutorials on Haskell *functions*, but have you tried reading a tutorial on *Haskell*? The code above suggests that you need to review many of the basic concepts and syntax of Haskell in general. I suggest taking a look at "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you seem to be missing some fundamentals about Haskell's syntax, and that would makes answering this question much more difficult than it should be. I second @Kwarrtz's suggestion that you have a look at [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), it's a great reference and tutorial for people just getting into the language. I'd also suggest [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/), which is still largely up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

as your main question is about writing .hs files please have a look at this:

```
module Main where

swap :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap i j xs = map f (zip [0..] xs)
  where f (k,x)
          | k == i = xj
          | k == j = xi
          | otherwise = x
        xi = xs !! i
        xj = xs !! j

main :: IO ()
main = print (swap 1 2 [1,2,3,4])
```

you can copy&paste this into an empty file and save it as `swap.hs` which you should be able to compile and load into GHCi just fine.

As you can see the file starts with a `module`-declaration then it defines your `swap` function (but well the implementation is  bit more involved as what you had in mind - and indeed this one is not the most efficient one).

It first introduces the type-signature (which is not necessary but usually a we do it at top-level functions) and starting from the next line implements the function.

Finally it gives the `main :: IO()` computation which is necessary in case you want to compile it into a executable program.

This computation just uses `swap` and prints out the result for your example.

---

#### remark

As this is homework you should re-implement at least the `swap` again by yourself.

You probably don't understand the way it works and it will use thinks you  cannot know for your course or may not use anyway - that's by design: you are supposed to remove the implementation and insert your own.